# printf function not working before the input

Tags: c

Im trying to write a program that get from the user some details and print the details to the screen , im waiting for printf to display orders for the input,and its not working.
only after i write the details the printf start to display the orders.
how can i fix this problem?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define THIS_YEAR 2018

int calcAge(int year);

int main() {

    char id[20];
    int year;
    char gender;
    float height;

    printf("Please enter your year birth\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    printf("Please enter your id\n");
    scanf("%s", id);

    printf("please enter your gender\n");
    scanf(" %c", &gender);

    printf("please enter your height\n");
    scanf("%f", &height);

    printf(
            "Your id : %s , your age : %d , your gender : %s , your height : %.2f",
            id, calcAge(year), (gender == 'f') ? "FEMALE" : "MALE", height);

    return 0;
}

int calcAge(int year) {

    return THIS_YEAR - year;
}
```

Output:

```
1991
203835568
f
1.73
Please enter your year birth
Please enter your id
please enter your gender
please enter your height
Your id : 203835568 , your age : 27 , your gender : FEMALE , your height : 1.73
```

Comment: `fflush(stdout)` before `scanf()`. – *`scanf("%s", id)`* never ever do that! Always specify a width when using `%s`!

Comment: it is strange the newline does not flush the output, what is your OS ?

Comment: Could you give some details about your system you try your appl. on? Though the `fflush(stdout)` (hinted by @Swordfish) may help, I wonder why it's necessary.

Comment: *I wonder why it's necessary.* – Me too.

Comment: btw, *`int main()` ~>* `int main(void)`

Comment: @Swordfish 
i did what you said , before every scanf i wrote "fflush(stdout)" and its working , ill read about that , can you explain why not to do "%s" like i did?

Comment: @Agar123 anyway what is your OS ? do you run on a terminal or under an IDE ?

Comment: @bruno : that should make no difference (IDE or not); the difference between a Linux _terminal_ and a Windows _console_ however is significant.

Comment: *can you explain why not to do "%s" like i did?* – ["scanf()" and "fscanf()" format strings should specify a field width for the "%s" string placeholder](https://rules.sonarsource.com/c/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-1079)

Comment: @Clifford you suppose all IDE worsk well, and that is false ;-)

Comment: Let me guess. Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: @Spikatrix Could be CLion as well.

Comment: @bruno  Point taken.  More generally the runtime environment as a whole is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you need to learn is that using `printf` writes to a `FILE *` named `stdout`.

The second thing you need to learn is that a `FILE *` is either buffered or unbuffered. Buffering means that the output you write (using e.g. `printf`) is stored in some internal memory before it's actually being written to the terminal.

By default, when `stdout` is connected to a normal terminal or console, then `stdout` is *line buffered*. Line buffered means that the contents of the buffers are written on newline. But if `stdout` is connected to a pipe (which is common for an IDE using its own handling of output) then `stdout` becomes *fully* buffered. Then the output is written only if the buffer becomes full, or you explicitly flush it (with e.g. `fflush(stdout)`).

In this case it  seems that you're running from such an IDE that turns `stdout` fully buffered.